# Proof of Partitions

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

Let $|n,k|$ denote the number of partitions of $n$ into $k$ distinct parts. Prove

$$|n,k| = |n-k,k-1| + |n-k,k|$$

Workings:

LHS counts the number of partitions of $n$ into $k$ distinct parts.

RHS:

Break this into two cases

I: $1$ is the smallest part

II: The smallest part is $>1$

I: This can be counted $|n-k,k-1|$ ways.

II: This can be counted $|n-k,k|$ ways.

Summing these together gives the RHS.

Edit: Is my proof correct?

Comment: What's the question here?

Comment: Oops I was wondering if my proof was correct

Comment: It is correct. You could rephrase it in a different way and it would be clearer, I'll add it as an answer so you may accept it if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simpler way to state the same is the following:

Suppose $A = \{a_0, …, a_{k-1} \}$ is a partition of $n$ into $k$ positive distinct integers. Then take the following partition:
$$
A' = \{a_0-1, …, a_{k-1}-1\}
$$
so
$$
\sum A' = n-k
$$
and $A'$ has either $k$ or $k-1$ distinct positive integers (at most one of them is $0$).

This process defines a function $f: P(n,k) \to P(n-k, k) \cup P(n-k, k-1)$.

On the other side, every partition $B \in P(n-k, k)$ can be transformed in a partition $B' \in P(n,k)$ by adding $1$ to each integer, and every partition $C \in P(n-k, k-1)$ can be taken to $C' \in P(n,k)$ by ading $1$ to each integer, and finally adding the integer $1$ itself.

It's now easy to show that these two functions are inverse one of the other, so they are bijections.

Comment: Well, if not "simpler" it's actually more formal.